# Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur

Tags: c#, azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a web application and of course on each phase I need to change the database schema on test server. When I tried to publish my code to my azure app service, it showed me an error:

> Error : .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 127,
>   Line 6 Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because
>   data loss might occur

I understand, it wants to delete some columns and of course some columns should be deleted. 
My question is, how can I tell it to Drop the columns anyway?!

### Update

I've removed all rows from affecting tables and the publishing went through. But there should be a way that I can keep my data and just drop that column.

besides, what is the solution on production?

### update 2

I have found [this post in msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d58a8e30-8903-4ae0-bb38-e59564437de6/rows-were-detected-the-schema-update-is-terminating-because-data-loss-might-occur?forum=vstsdb)  mentioning that: **you can uncheck the "Block the update if data loss might occur" option under Data | Schema Compare | Schema compare options.**

But I guess that is only there if you have a database project. how to do it on code first?

Answer (score 0):

Look at adding a deployment script to your project. This allows you to do things with T-SQL that are blocked for data integrity reasons on a publish. I'm not positive if this is available for the specific type of project you are doing, but I've used them in the past to do a blocked schema changes on a database project.